# How to update react state object array

Tags: reactjs, reactive-programming

I need to know how to update the array of users inside the state to accept a new user object.

The state users array contains id and name only.

When i try to use update addon to push an item in the users array.

```
var newUser = {id:1, name:'Foo'};
let newState = update(this.state, {users: {$push: [newUser]}});
```

"react-dom.js:17858 Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, name}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the render method of `UsersTable`.(…)"

Comment: Did you try the method(s) mentioned in the error message? For instance, replace the `{id:...}` with `[id:...]` and it should work?

Comment: I have the same problem too.

Answer (score 1):

You are mutating state. Instead try:

```
const users = this.state.users
users.push(newUser)
this.setState(Object.assign({}, this.state, { users }}))
```

Comment: better way to perform this: `this.setState((prevState) => { users: prevState.users.push(newUser) })`